# Why does trim(" ") == "" returns false in Fortran?

Tags: null, fortran, trim, nonblank

I'm facing a random incoherence... In some cases, trim(" ") == "" returns false.

I did something like this (so a sort of concatenation function using types) of course this code is a bit messy a lot of simplification can be done but because of this trim problem I did it like this to be sure that nothing is messing :

```
character*150 :: tab(5)
character*150 :: var
character*50 :: a
character*50 :: b
character*50 :: c
character*50 :: d
a= '' ! comes from a type nameType%pref
b= '' ! parameter
c= '' ! comes from a type nameType%suf
d= 'deviceName' ! parameter
if (trim(d) .ne. '') then
    var = d
else
    if (trim(c) .ne. ''  .and. (trim(a) .ne. '' .or. trim(b) .ne. ''))then
            var = trim(a)//trim(c)//trim(b)
    else
        var = ''
    end if
end if
var = trim(a)//trim(b)//trim(c)
tab(1) = var
if (trim(tab(1)) .eq. '') then
     print*, ("hi")
end if
```

Here is the exit at the end of this function :

```
trim(var) :
len_trim(var) :            0 
trim(var) == " : T
```

This code is sometimes working and sometimes not... (I mean I have other empty variables and I'm facing this problem only with some variables) I think the space character is encrypted because in debug mode I have random values like "pÏ"...

Here is the exit at the error printing and when I ask for the ASCII value  :

```
    trim(var) : 
    len_trim(var) :          150
    trim(var) == " : F
    ichar(var(j:j)), ">"//var(j:j)//"<"
           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >           0 >
```

So trim(tab(i)) is doing a trim of 150 NULL.

I created this function to solve that problem :

```
      logical function isNULL(var)
          implicit none
          Character *(*) :: var
          logical :: ret
          ret = ichar(var(1:1)) .eq. 0
          isNULL = ret
          return 
      end function
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. This is a coding site and if you have a problem with some code, you must show the code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @vladimirF I went through the code, I finally found out that my problem is totally different from why I first thought...

Comment: I can not reproduce the error, when I compile the code with intel fortran compiler or gfortran, in both cases it prints the `hi` as expected.

Comment: @chw21 for me sometimes in some cases it doesn't do the correct think... But this is a simplified version of my code... There are 3 functions modifying a, b, and c at the end I have an array of var and all is empty (I checked that in debug mode) but my code is style considering "" non equal to ""...
And what is funny is that the same exact code was also not working and without modifying anything, it starts working... And now I'm facing this problem again...

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is to compare `LEN_TRIM(var)` to zero. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LEN_005fTRIM.html

Comment: Hi @ailyc, welcom to Stack OVerflow. CAn you minimize your code. The entire `if` condition in your example is a bit of code-bloat here. Could you reduce it? Also, what does the following program return? `program trim_test
  print *, trim(" "), len_trim(" "), trim(" ") == ""
end program`

Comment: P lease note if you are using Trim and Len_trim this is not Fortran77, so I've removed the tag (and I'm glad to see you are not using a totally outdated tool which should not have been used for around 1/4 century)

Comment: .f can be any Fortran 66 or 2018, it does not matter. .f90 can be any from 90 to 2018. Also, these tools normally cannot force you to use Fortran 77, they can only force you to use the fixed source form. Abaqus is similar, it does **not** require Fortran 77, it just requires the fixed source form = the .f file. But you can have Fortran 2018 in this form.

Comment: @VladimirF oh ok good to know that.

Comment: @kvantour I found the result of that, I edited my post...

Comment: Please make a testable [mcve], otherwise no-one can help you.

Comment: @kvantour How can I print that ?

Comment: Let me rewrite that comment, because of auto-correction, it turned into mumbo-jumbo:  My suspicion is that you are reading a DOS file with CRLF terminations and that your string actually ends with a non-printable character. Can you print out the 150 ASCII values of each character? (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `TRIM` does:

> **7.170 `TRIM (STRING)`**
>   **Description:** String without trailing blanks.
>   **Class:** Transformational function.
>   **Argument:** `STRING` shall be a character scalar.
>   **Result Characteristics:** Character with the same kind type parameter value as `STRING` and with a length that is the length of `STRING` less the number of trailing blanks in `STRING`. If `STRING` contains no nonblank
>   characters, the result has zero length.
>   **Result Value:** The value of the result is the same as `STRING` except any trailing blanks are removed.
>   **Example:** `TRIM (" A B ")` has the value `" A B"`.
>
> **<sub>source: [Fortran 2008 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf)</sub>**

As you notice, the word *blank*, is appearing a lot in this definition and represents a white space in the respective character set.

My suspicion is that you are processing data coming from a DOS-box which has CRLF line termination. Or any other unprintable character at the end of your string. You could verify this by printing each character of the string and it's corresponding ASCII number.

Eg if your string is `str`:

```
   do i=1,len(str)
      print *, ichar(str(i:i)), ">"//str(i:i)//"<"
   done
```

whitespace characters should have value 32. If you have a different value, you can have a look here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @ailyc I'm happy it helped you out.

Comment: If we do not know exactly how the values are being assigned to your string, it is difficult to help. Did you initialize your string with an empty string? It is possible that the compiler initializes the memory with zero. So if you would do something like `str=""`, you should be fine.

Comment: I can't change the value of a variable more than once in easy5 as my variable is already modified... So I'm trying to look for a "isnull" function or an equivalent to add it to my tests... I'm thinking about something like : "ichar(str(1:1)) == 0"